# Построение карты вознаграждений q-learning

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, машинное-обучение

Всех приветствую. Хочу поближе познакомиться с Reinforcement  learning'ом.

Появилась такая проблема:

К примеру, у меня есть машина и изображение из машины, типа такого:

[image: road]

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы машина ехала прямо посередине этих линий.

Но тут проблема:

Чтобы "дать" алгоритму награду за то, что он держится линии - мне нужно знать где эта линия! То есть, чтобы научить алгоритм держаться линии - мне нужно обучить стороннюю модель определять эту самую линию?

Как мне быть? Как дать модели понять, что если она держится линии - это хорошо, а если уезжает от нее - плохо?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Данных недостаточно для такого сложного вопроса так что в некоторых случаях буду опираться на логики и предположения.
первое предположение камера находится всегда в зафиксированном положении. и всегда одинаковая(угол обзора не меняется).
Тут по мимо нейросети потребуется ещё дополнительное по.
Я бы изначально сделал раскадровку и разбил бы изображение на сетку.примерно 12 на 10 (12 столбцов 10 строк)
Далее наложить на изображение примерную траекторию в зависимости от того куда повёрнуты колёса (потребуется отдельные датчики) и математическая модель.
(накладывать надо от цента снизу).

Далее отрезать верхнюю часть изображение она нам на первых этапах вообще не понадобиться.
Далее обучить видеть эти самые линии, (линя белая фон черный)
самый нижний ряд проверочный, если на нём линия траектории пересеклась с линией разметки это максимальный штраф, или если расстояние от траектории до одной из линий меньше чем до второй это уже грубая ошибка.
расстояние от траектории до правой линии берём за **x**
расстояние от траектории до левой линии  берём за **y**
x-y (или y-x в зависимости что больше x или y) 
умножаем на коэффициент ошибки (значение должно всегда быть положительным).
далее тоже самое проделываем со  вторым рядом с низу но тут уже коэффициент должен быть меньше.
а если во втором ряду

```
x-y < ((x+y)/2)/10
```

(разница расстояний до боковых линий меньше 10% от среднего расстояния от цента до боковой линии) тогда уже можно поощрение.

Точно также и с каждым линией только коэффициенты меняются в разных рядах изображения.
чем ниже ряд в изображении тем больше ошибка но меньше поощрение
и соответственно наоборот чем выше ряд тем меньше цена ошибки и выше цена поощрения.
    **p.s.** Надеюсь хоть немного поможет.
Объяснять я не умею =D

```
**p.p.s**
```

Основано на моих попытках научить ардуинку кататься по линии. (практически противоположная задача.) 
Ещё и автораспознование примает p.p.s за фрагмент кода.